# Allowing SSH access from codeship - opening firewall to EC2 east coast IPs

Tags: amazon-ec2, capistrano, continuous-deployment, codeship

I am trying to implement automatic deployment from Codeship by using a Capistrano style script to allow it to SSH onto my servers and pull from my git repository after my tests have passed. The problem is that SSH access to the servers is restricted by IP address, and Codeship advise that you should open up your firewall to the range of IP addresses that AWS use for their east coast EC2 instances: https://codeship.com/documentation/faq/enabling-access-to-servers/

However, I am not sure about doing this because there is a large number of IP addresses: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

My concern is, apart from this being a tedious process (there are 43 IP address ranges for east coast EC2), does this not defeat the purpose of restricting IP addresses, as it would make this precaution useless if a potential attacker were to use an east coast EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your instance is hosted within the same region as Codeship (us-east-1) then your best bet is to setup an EC2 security group [as described here](https://codeship.com/documentation/faq/enabling-access-to-servers/).

I appreciate that this isn't the case for everyone, so assuming you're using iptables then I'd suggest a similar approach to that described in [CloudFlare's documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169166-How-do-I-whitelist-CloudFlare-s-IP-addresses-in-iptables-) and to setup a bash script run through a crontab to keep the current ip ranges up to date should they change.

In regards to security, since you're opening the port to the entire AWS region, yes there is an increased attack surface. It sounds like you've already disabled password auth, so brute force attacks are unlikely, but a sensibly configured fail2ban jail should take care of most of the nasties.